# ¿Cómo eliminar un valor introducido por formulario en JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaría eliminar una palabra y su definición (introducidos vía formulario a través de una caja de texto) con JQuery.

Tengo el siguiente html:

```html
<div id="definiciones"> 
        <h2> Definiciones</h2>
        <label for="palabra">Palabra</label>
        <input type="text" name="palabra" id="palabra"/> <br />
        <label for="concepto">Concepto</label>
        <input type="text" name="concepto" id="concepto"/> <br />
        <input type="button" value="Añade definicion" id="añadeDefinicion" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Quitar definiciones" id="quitaDefinicion" /> <br />
        <h4>Lista de Definiciones</h4>
        <dl id="listaDefiniciones">
        </dl>
</div>
```

Y en el javascript tengo el botón recogido y una función que añade una definición (funciona).

```javascript
$(function(){

    $("#añadeDefinicion").click(añadirDefinicion);

});

function añadirDefinicion (){
    var palabra = $("#palabra").val(); 
    var concepto = $("#concepto").val(); 
if (palabra!="" && concepto!="") { 
    var padre = $("#listaDefiniciones"); 
    var nuevodt=$("<dt></dt>").text(palabra); 
    var nuevodd=$("<dd></dd>").text(concepto);
    padre.append(nuevodt); 
    padre.append(nuevodd);
}else { //Si los campos están vacíos, lanza una alerta
    alert("Alguno de los campos está vacío. Escribe algo!")
 }
} //fin funcion añadirDefinicion
```

La pregunta es esa, con esos parámetros, ¿cómo podría hacer para eliminar una palabra (y su definición) que haya introducido anteriormente?
Ejemplo con lo que tengo hasta ahora:

[image: Ejemplo de lo que se ve hasta ahora]

Es decir, quiero que al apretar el botón "quitar definiciones" me coja el valor de la caja de texto "palabra" y me elimine esa palabra (en el ejemplo "perro") y las definiciones asociadas (en el ejemplo "animal de cuatro patas").
Gracias.

Comment: Sugerencia: ¿No seria más practico que pusieras un boton pequeño al lado de cada definición para su eliminación?  Lo digo porque parece raro la forma en que quieres hacerlo.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que me lo piden de esa forma, pero no soy capaz de dar con la tecla.

Comment: ¿Lo de `Añadir definición` te funciona?  No veo el codigo donde lo haces (me refiero a que no veo como recoges el evento de darle al boton).  Debes poner un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), sino perdemos interes en ayudarte porque nos lo tenemos que trabajar nosotros

Comment: Sí, no lo había añadido. Ahora ya está.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirando tu código veo que una posible solución, y aprovechando las funcionalidades de la api de [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/), seria la siguiente.

Agrega este código a tu javascript:

```
$( "#quitaDefinicion" ).click(function() {
  quitarDefinicion();
});

function quitarDefinicion() {
  var palabra = $("#palabra").val();
  $('dt:contains("' + palabra + '")').next().remove();
  $('dt:contains("' + palabra + '")').remove();
} //fin funcion quitarDefinicion
```

***Explicación:***

1. Primero captamos el evento click del botón con id `quitarDefinicion` mediante la función `.click` de jQuery que ya conoces, y le ponemos como única acción llamar a la función `quitarDefinicion` (aunque no hace falta, puedes poner su contenido en el `click` mismo, pero a efectos de comprensión lo he puesto así).
2. Creamos una función `quitarDefinicion()` que básicamente captura la palabra a eliminar del input con id `palabra` (*`val()`*) y que primero busca el elemento  que sigue immediatamente (*`next()`*) al elemento indicado (*`dt`*) que a su vez contenga el valor de la palabra (*`contains()`*).  Con esto conseguimos identificar el elemento **`dd`** que acompaña a esa definición de termino *`dt`*. Y lo borramos primero (antes que el propio término! eso es importante). Es decir, esto:

   ```
   $('dt:contains("' + palabra + '")').next().remove();
   ```

   Y luego eliminamos del DOM la propia definición de término buscada:

   ```
   $('dt:contains("' + palabra + '")').remove();
   ```

Evidentemente no es lo más óptimo, pero sí lo más facil de implementar dado tu código actual.  Sino habria que reescribirlo entero y no entra dentro del ámbito de esta respuesta hacerlo.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y parece que funciona perfectamente. Yo estaba intentando hacer una función para buscar la palabra, que me devolviese su posición en un índice y que luego se eliminase la posición del dt a la que correspondía, pero esto creo que es más sencillo y mejor, porque lo otro que estaba planteando yo me daba problemas. Muchas gracias :) Por cierto, en este caso se puede acceder directamente al dt porque solo hay uno, ¿no? Lo digo porque parece que no es necesario usar la id="listaDefiniciones" (que contiene el dl en el que se engloban las definiciones que añado).

Comment: A ver, la solucion que he puesto es exclusivamente para el contexto que has preguntado, y en ese contexto funciona. Si quieres practicar con el encontrarás tu código en esta web: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcmg34xh/  donde puedes editarlo como quieras y ejecutarlo mediante el botón RUN, y asi verificar tus cambios.  Lo del indice tambien lo habia pensado, pero entonces hubiera tenido que reescribir tu codigo a conciencia, y no creia que eso te ayudara en nada, así que he optado por la solución simple y sencilla (aunque no es perfecta, ya te daras cuenta supongo, pues quedan muchas cosas en el aire)

Comment: Gracias también por la recomendación de esa página, estoy empezando con el tema y no la conocía. Una cosa, el uso de las comillas simples y dobles en este caso: $('dt:contains("' + palabra + '")').next().remove(); por lo que veo es invariable, ¿no? Es decir, tiene que ser ese uso de comillas sí o sí para que funcione.

Comment: Si, al principio cuesta un poco de entender la mezcla de comillas que teoricamente encierran strings (cadenas) como por ejemplo `"Mi casa de campo es bonita"` pero si quieres reemplazar `campo` por una variable la tienes que sacar de la cadena asi: `"Mi casa de " + variable + " es bonita"`.  Eso es lo facil, pero luego se complica cuando te encuentras con esto: `'dt:contains("' + palabra + '")'` porque es una cadena que debe ir entrecomillada, pero a su vez ya tenia una comilla simple que la cubria, y de ahi esa sintaxis.  Si quitas la variable seria asi: `'dt:contains("perro")'`

Comment: Vale, gracias :)